# Echo last entry into MySql table first, followed by the next most previous entry

Tags: php

I have a very simple database table of posts, I'd like to be able to print the most recent entry first, followed then by the next most previous entry etc etc when I retrieve them all . How do I do this?

```
$someText = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM text");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($someText)) {
        echo "$row[column]";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to order them by `id` or `date` or something else. (`ASC` or `DESC`)

This might do the trick if you've added them in the correct order.

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test)) {
    echo "$row[post]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL statement, `"SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY <date_time_field> DESC"` If you don't have a date_time_field, you can use the primary key (usually id).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to order them by date, the MySQL would be like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC
```